# PHP code in WordPress page template doesn't execute

Tags: php, wordpress

Can anyone tell me why this code in a wordpress 'page template' doesn't execute?

'Echo' seem to work but all 'include' and 'print_r()' and other functions don't. This exact code works on my home server but not on wordpress hosted site:

```
<?php

/**
 * Template Name: fbshares
 *
 * A custom page template for displaying all posts.
 *
 * The "Template Name:" bit above allows this to be selectable
 * from a dropdown menu on the edit page screen.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Ten
 * @since Twenty Ten 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">
<div id="content" role="main" class="fullpagejoel">

 <?php 
    echo "x";
    $url = "http://www.google.com";

    $social = array(
        'twitter' => 'http://cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url=',
        'facebook' => 'https://graph.facebook.com/',
        'stumbleupon' => 'http://www.stumbleupon.com/services/1.01/badge.getinfo?url='
    );

    $json = file_get_contents($social['twitter'].$url, false);
    $a = json_decode($json, true);
    $r['twitter'] = $a['count'];

    print_r($a);
    echo count($a).' [OK]';

 ?>
```

Comment: How can you say it does not work? Do you get an error? And where is the `include`?

Comment: I took away the include and tried debugging. I put the code instead directly in the page (what you see up there). I get no errors nothing. Just a "exit". I can't get it to give me error message either by setting `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a debugging service. We're not going to guess whether you have errors or wait for you to try different things. You may want to try Code Review.

Comment: Ok then change my question to "How to add PHP code in Wordpress templates". I've been posting on StackOverflow for many years and this seems legit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem. After debugging every bit item by item, the problem is that WordPress doesn't allow you to run `file_get_contents`, instead you have to use `wp_remote_get` like this:

```
GOOD: $json = wp_remote_get( $social['twitter'].$url );
BAD: $json = file_get_contents($social['twitter'].$url, false);
```

I just wasted a full day on this so I hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have enough rep to comment, but have you checked the source?  WordPress dies silently, but often there is something in the source.

Short answer though, yes, you can execute any php you want in a template.  I just copy pasted it into a WordPress template on our test server and it ran fine.

Comment: Could the hosting company (Netfirms.ca) deactivate some PHP functions in wordpress?

Comment: They could, I know that GoDaddy does with things like the eval(base64_decode()).  Have you asked them?