# DOMDocument in WordPress php file?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am editing the wp-comments-post.php file in WordPress. I tried running the following code in non wordpress program and it returned all the URLs in the http://mysmallwebpage.com/ website. But when I put the following code inside wp-comments-post.php file, `DOMDocument` seems to not work. Can you please tell me if I am doing anything wrong here.

```
if ( 'abc' == $comment_content )//if the comment page only have the letters abc
{
    $html = file_get_contents("http://mysmallwebpage.com/");
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);    
    $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

    foreach ($links as $link)
    {       
       $returnLink =  $link->getAttribute('href');
       if (strpos($returnLink, 'http') === 0) //To check if the line contain the keyword 'http'
       {
           $returnLink = "<a href=\"$returnLink\">$returnLink</a>";
           array_push($URL_List, (string)$returnLink);
           //I inserted the following wordpress termination code to see if it contain at least one element
           wp_die( __('<strong>ERROR</strong>: Program Reached here! ') );
       }
    }
    //if I put wp_die( …… ), It works in this location. Just not above.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the way the poster resolved his problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094933/php-code-in-wordpress-page-template-doesnt-execute), try using `wp_remote_get` instead of `file_get_contents`. Don't disable error checking when you're trying to solve a problem; it's likely that `loadHTML` is failing because `file_get_contents` isn't returning anything, but using the at-sign deprives you of this information.