# Using getElementsByTagName in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-parsing

I have a really simple script to read from an XML file:

```
<?php 

$xml_data=wp_remote_get("http://example.com/connectioncounts"); 

  //$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
  //$doc->load($xml_data); 

  $wms = $xml_data->getElementsByTagName('Tag'); 
  $currentlistener = $wms->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("ConnectionsCurrent")->item(0)->nodeValue; 
  $listenerhits = $wms->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("ConnectionsTotal")->item(0)->nodeValue; 

  echo "Current listener: $currentlistener<br> Total hits: $listenerhits"; 

?>
```

I am using `wp_remote_get` as Wordpress doesn't seem to like `file_get_contents` as referred by [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094933/php-code-in-wordpress-page-template-doesnt-execute).

The problem is when I run that code I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method WP_Error::getElementsByTagName() in /home/user/public_html/test/wp-content/themes/headway/library/common/functions.php(405) : eval()'d code on line 10
```

I figured that similar to how Wordpress doesn't like `file_get_contents`, maybe there is some function for `getElementsByTagName`?

Comment: because that function do not return an xml object and has not function like that, this function returns `(WP_Error|array)`

Comment: `wp_remote_get` is returning a `WP_Error` object. Call `$xml_data->get_error_message()` to get the error message. Also, there is no reason you cannot use `file_get_contents` with WordPress. My guess is the reason you're having an issue with it is because the `allow_url_fopen` directive is disabled in your php.ini

Comment: `var_dump($xml_data)`. you'll see it's **NOT** a dom object, therefore it will not have a gEBTN() method...

Comment: OK so trying to fix this... when I switch it to `file_get_contents` and try to load a DOMDocument like this:

  `$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
  $doc->load($xml_data); `

I am getting a new error:

`Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Empty string supplied as input`
`Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object`

Comment: `DOMDocument::load()` expects the path to an xml file, not the raw contents of an xml file. Use `DOMDocument::loadXML` to load an xml string. Also, from the error message it looks like fetching the file contents did not work. You should dump the result of `file_get_contents` (or `wp_remote_get`) to make sure you have a valid xml document before attempting to load it.

Comment: Thanks @mtinsley, I will give it a shot. It should be a valid XML file as I'm trying to fetch the contents of [Wowza connection info](http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?8011-Display-current-listeners-using-PHP)